# Linux script to transfer (ID3) tags from FLAC to MP3

Tags: linux, scripting, mp3, flac, id3v2

For my media server, I am looking for ways to transfer tags from my FLAC files to MP3.

In a bash script, I can extract tags using [metaflac](https://xiph.org/flac/documentation_tools_metaflac.html) to local vars, but when tagging mp3 with id3v2, I seem to lose national characters (guess it must be unicode?)

Also I need to be able to set replay gain tags, and album art (all present in the FLAC's).

I am looking for a scripted solution to run unattended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this tool [eyed3](http://eyed3.nicfit.net). It supports album art embedding, text encoding in latin1, utf8, utf16-BE and utf16-LE. However the replay gain is not supported. As far as I understand it is not widely supported.

Comment: This was the best solution so far. It seems I can even set the replay gain values (extracted from FLAC) using --set-user-text-frame. Only challenge is the "year" tag, which can be set, and apparently read again with eyeD3, but it is not readable by mp3Tag (for Windows).

Comment: Non-ascii characters are warned: "'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position XX: ordinal not in range(128)", but the non-ascii characters are perfectly inserted in new tags.

Comment: Year issue solved: eyeD3 uses ID3v2.4 tags as default. Metadata for year are more complex in this version. eyeD3 -Y writes to the TDRL (Release Date) tag, whereas mp3tag (and others) look for year in the TDRC (Recording time) tag.

Changing my tagging script to include --set-text-frame=TDRC:"$DATE" solves my problem.

Answer (score 10):

If you are interested in a Python solution, the mutagen library looks really good.

It could be as easy as:

```
from mutagen.flac import FLAC
from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3

flacfile = FLAC("flacfile.flac")
mp3file = EasyID3("mp3file.mp3")

for tag in flacfile:
    if tag in EasyID3.valid_keys.keys():
        mp3file[tag] = flacfile[tag]

mp3file.save()
```

I found this solution for copying mp3 id3 tags into FLAC files.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to use the save option to force 1D3v2.3 for compatibility with Windows 7 file explorer. Mutagen wants to use v2.4 instead by default, but the save options allow you to change it:

mp3file.save(None, 1, 3)

First 2 arguments are default filename and what to do with v1 tags, third argument is v2 point version.

https://mutagen.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/id3.html?highlight=save#mutagen.id3.ID3.save

Answer (score 3):

Victor's solution showed me the way. It may fail, however, if copying tags to a file you've just converted, for example, from flac to mp3. That is, it will fail if the file you are copying tags to doesn't already have any tags.

So you may need to prime the destination file first, giving it the means to have tags.

```
from mutagen import File
from mutagen.flac import FLAC
from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3
from mutagen.id3 import ID3, ID3NoHeaderError

def convert_tags(f1,f2):
    # f1: full path to file copying tags from
    # f2: full path to file copying tags to
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873364/linux-script-to-transfer-id3-tags-from-flac-to-mp3
    # http://stackoverflow.com/a/18369606/2455413
    try:
        meta = EasyID3(f2)
    except ID3NoHeaderError:
        meta = File(f2, easy=True)
        meta.add_tags()
        meta.save()
    from_f = FLAC(f1)
    to_f = EasyID3(f2)
    for tag in from_f:
        if tag in EasyID3.valid_keys.keys(): to_f[tag] = from_f[tag]
    to_f.save()
    return
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution using ffmpeg.
Eg. just define a bash function in $HOME/.bashrc:

```sh
flac2mp3() 
{ 
  ffmpeg -i "$1" -ab 320k -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 "$(basename "$1" flac)mp3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Quod Libet](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.io/) comes with a command line tool called [operon](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/commands/operon.html) that does this and more:

```bash
operon copy song.flac song.mp3
```

Since Quod Libet is built on Mutagen, it knows about a bunch of obscure tags and how to translate them among the various tagging formats, which is important for some workflows. The only quirk I noticed is that it doesn't copy tags with empty values, but that doesn't bother me.