# what's the difference between eyed3 and eyeD3, and how can i edit mp3 tags with python

Tags: tags, mp3, eyed3

I'm trying to update my mp3 tags through python.
I've downloaded eyed3, but i can only import eyed3 and not eyeD3. 
I saw some options for code with eyeD3 that do what i need. for example something like:

```
tag = eyeD3.Tag()
tag.link(mp3_file_name)
tag.setVersion([2,3,0])
tag.setArtist(u'\u897f\u306f\u3058\u3081')
tag.update()
```

But i can't do that with eyed3.
Does someone knows what's the difference between eyed3 and eyeD3 and how can i download eyeD3?
Or does anyone knows a different way to edit tags for mp3 file?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I did not get eyed3 to work well, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18369606/2550406) offers a working alternative

Answer (score 2):

In the latest version i.e eyeD3 0.8 the import module has been changed from

**import eyeD3** to **import eyed3**
and the usage is :

```
import eyed3

audio = eyed3.load(PATH_TO_YOUR_MP3)
#To retrieve Data
print audio.tag.artist
print audio.tag.album
print audio.tag.title

#To set Data
audio.tag.artist = u"ARTIST"
audio.tag.album= u"ALBUM"
audio.tag.title= u"TITLE"
audio.tag.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

`eyeD3` is the command-line tool (e.g. eyeD3 --help), and `eyed3` is the Python you can import. They are both part of the eyeD3 PyPI package.

Note, older versions of this software did name the module eyeD3 but this changed in version 0.7.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the difference is, I believe its actually the same package, eyed3 works as you require, you just need to pass save rather than update:

```
audiofile = eyed3.load("song.mp3")
audiofile.tag.artist = u"Nobunny"
audiofile.tag.album = u"Love Visions"
audiofile.tag.album_artist = u"Various Artists"
audiofile.tag.title = u"I Am a Girlfriend"
audiofile.tag.track_num = 4

audiofile.tag.save()
```