# Convert Music to 432 Hz and save metadata (like album cover, artist, album artist etc.)

Tags: converters, mp3

Like in title - is it can be done? I tried many ways (ffmpeg, 432 Batch converter, audacity) - every time covers and other metadata disappears.

I have a lot of songs - every each one of them is with cover, genre etc., so it is easier to organize music. Really wouldn't like to do it all over again (+600 songs)

Comment: Why don't you just play them back a bit slower instead?

Comment: MP3 files can only exist between 8000 and 48000 Hz. Also see Q and As for [Linux script to transfer (ID3) tags from FLAC to MP3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8873364/4299358).